# Need to convert my Time string to a timestamp to update current timestamp field in firestore

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I am trying to convert my Time string that displays in my app as 11:00. I need to convert to a timestamp so I can replace the current Time field in my firestore which is a timestamp.

I have tried using moment.js to update the field but it changes the data type to a string.

Current value in my firestore is shown below

[image]

```
submitJob = () => {

const { navigation } = this.props;
const customer_jobnumber = navigation.getParam('JobNumber', 'No Job Number');
const customer_starttime = navigation.getParam('datetime', 'No Job Start Time');
const customer_end = navigation.getParam('datetimefinish', 'No Job Finish Time');



firebase.firestore().collection("jobs").doc(customer_jobnumber).update({ endtime: customer_end, starttime: customer_starttime, value: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() });}
```

The desired value would be - October 4, 2020 at 11:00:00 AM UTC+1

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution with this, if anyone comes across the same problem.

```
let tx = customer_starttime.split(":")
let dx = new Date().setHours(parseInt(tx[0]),parseInt(tx[1]),0)
let dl = new Date(dx)
```